# how to change map on clicking a button

Tags: php, sql-server, php-5.3

I currently have a Google map that outputs markers for values from my database. The query that currently does this in my php script is:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT gps_lat, gps_long, quality
FROM         V6_HOLLTS479_20101015_subset.dbo.rvresults_tie_parent
WHERE quality=1
```

Basically I need to add buttons (for example button for "quality 1", "quality 2", "quality 3", "quality 4" etc) on the page. When clicking on the button it changed the query to "WHERE quality=3" for example.

I've been looking at different way into how to do this and I think a switch statement would do the job, but I'm not sure how it would look and how to implement it in this situation. Could anyone provide some example code or advice on how to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 2):

In your form all quality buttons should have the same name:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="quality_button" value="Quality 1" />
  <input type="submit" name="quality_button" value="Quality 2" />
  <input type="submit" name="quality_button" value="Quality 3" />
</form>
```

After submit use the following code to process the form:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  switch ($_POST['quality_button']) {
    case 'Quality 1':
      // Update your SQL query
      break;
    case 'Quality 2':
      // Update your SQL query
      break;
    case 'Quality 3':
      // Update your SQL query
      break;
    default:
      // If non matched do something else here or do nothing.
      break;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Giedrius Rekasius for your very speedy reply! Your code worked a treat! Managed to get it working! Cheers Neil